# Facet search guideline for using unique attribute as facet attribute

Tags: apache, solr, facet, faceted-search, design-consideration

What does the facet search design guide line say about using an unique attribute of the indexed item as configured one of the facet attribute?

I am looking for some documented proof.

In my opinion, this does not make sense. Facet on unique attribute is bad work around of search by id. This will make the facet panel unusable with long frustrating scroll to surpass the unique id list to move to other relevant attributes.

Comment: Your question does not really make any sense. Specifically "unique attribute of the indexed item". Could you refer to a specific example that ships with Solr or something similar. As it is, the question is neither answerable nor useful to anybody else.

Comment: This may not be a staight forward question and surely there is no techical soluiton to this. This is a design consideration ask.

By "Unique Attribute of the indexed item" , I mean - 
Product.code. Take any ecommerce product to be the indexed item and code of the product will always be unique. Product.code will be indexed with the product as one of the attribute.

However, what if the product.code is made facet attribute along with the product.category or product.color or product.price.

Comment: I have already shared my point of view as well that this does not look right and looking for some facet design principle guideline documentation to resonate.

Comment: I still don't get it. Don't make product.code as a facet. You have middleware in front of Solr, it can control which fields are available to facet on. Just facet on those that make sense for your business case.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch Is there a way I may reach out to you. I want to discuss this.

Comment: Not to me directly, but the Solr Users mailing list is a good place to discuss more complex scenarios. It has a lot more people with much higher level of knowledge. But you do need to formulate your question better.